# Way to make overflow-y:auto stick to the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm using angular's double binding to continually add to a string on button clicks and when it gets too long for the box, the scrollbar appears. This works just fine. I was wondering if there was a way to have to scrollbar jump to the bottom when the string is modified and the page updated instead of staying still.

I'm using this on the html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Roll History</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" id="rollHistory">
    <pre ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" id="rollDetails" >{{rollHistory}}</pre>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="clearHistory()">Clear History</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Which is tied to a whole bunch of calculations in my angular controller which continuously appends to the rollHistory. And all I have on CSS is

```
#rollHistory {
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: Something like this perhaps: `$("#rollHistory").scrollTop($("#rollHistory").innerHeight());`

Comment: Mmm, ok, I think this could work, but I'm a little uncertain how to incorporate this into angular.

Comment: Could this work: `var $el = $("#rollHistory"); $el.scrollTop($id[0].scrollHeight);`?

Comment: Tried plopping that into the function that gets called when the button is clicked and I got an error stating: $id is not defined

Comment: My bad. It should be: `var $el = $("#rollHistory"); $el.scrollTop($el[0].scrollHeight);`

Comment: That worked! Well, for some reason it's not going all the way to the bottom, it's stopping about a quarter inch short of the bottom, clipping off the very last entry. Maybe I have some css causing that, maybe it's cause it's inside a panel? but otherwise this is working great.

Comment: I tried it and it seems indeed to go all the way to the bottom.

Comment: I went ahead and pushed it to production. You can see it here: http://www.firexion.com/dice and the code is here: https://github.com/Firexion/hundred. If you click one of the quick roll buttons a few dozen times, it'll roll over to where the roll history is beyond full and you can see that while it is scrolling down, it isn't scrolling all the way down for some reason. Very confusing :/

Comment: yeah, that's strange indeed. But like I said I don't know AngularJS too well. You sure you can't use a jQuery solution?

Comment: I'm not sure how well angular plays with jQuery. I guess this will work for now. I'll play around with it a bit and see if I can get it to work. Thank you so much for all your help.

Comment: If you're curious I think I may've found the culprit, I had changed the font size from the standard to 16px and after I removed that, it sent it perfectly to the bottom. I guess the font-size was screwing it up or something.

Comment: Oh ok! Well, good you got it working. Cheers! :)

Comment: I still see the issue on the test page you mentioned (in Firefox). Regardless of any font-size and whatnot, I’d suggest you just add a “safety margin” onto the read scrollHeight value, say `100` – that should guarantee your element will always be scrolled to the very bottom, no matter what (and the browsers don’t mind if you set `scrollTop` to a higher value than “technically” mathematically possible for the element).

Comment: Ah, sorry about that, I didn't push those changes onto production. I'll do that when I get home for lunch in four hours.  If you want to look at it before that, you could modify it with firebug.  I did try adding a value to the scrollHeight but that didn't seem to effect it at all. I think the problem is because it's a pre inside a  div inside a panel, so I think it goes to the bottom of the pre (which is the one with the scrollbar element) but not to the bottom of the panel

Comment: Just to let you know CBroe, those changes are on the website now, so you can see that with the font change it moves it to the bottom of it (though not quite to the bottom of the panel, but enough so that nothing gets cut off)